# posting a file with curl command?

Tags: curl

Hi i am having a curl command to post data .

```
 curl -v  -X POST "http://localhost:8080/api/files" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJnbG9iYWxhZG1pbkBsb2NhbGhvc3QiLCJhdXRoIjoiUk9MRV9HTE9CQUxfURNSU4iLCJleHAiOjE1NTg2MjQ2NjF9.XV8Ibcqoh7a6FWN6BF89rH4abyraaS86jsP04Y5vuNrH-rnJ3Se0T7ogA0t7oXXzrVsvZUpPgkm5pGHotd6a_g" -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data1" -F "file=@feet.wbmp;type=image/jpeg"
```

what is the difference if i use this command without ;type=image/jpeg

```
curl -v  -X POST "http://localhost:8080/api/files" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJnbG9iYWxhZG1pbkBsb2NhbGhvc3QiLCJhdXRoIjoiUk9MRV9HTE9CQUxfURNSU4iLCJleHAiOjE1NTg2MjQ2NjF9.XV8Ibcqoh7a6FWN6BF89rH4abyraaS86jsP04Y5vuNrH-rnJ3Se0T7ogA0t7oXXzrVsvZUpPgkm5pGHotd6a_g" -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data1" -F "file=@feet.wbmp"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### tl;dr

The `type` option allows you to specify the [`Content-Type`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) of a given part, in a multipart request.

---

The [`-F`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F) option (and the more verbose [`--form`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F)) emulates a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. It will make curl to `POST` data using the [`Content-Type`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) header with the [`multipart/form-data`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578) value.

In multipart requests, each part may have an optional [`Content-Type`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) header, as stated in the [RFC 7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578):

> [**4.4.  Content-Type Header Field for Each Part**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578#section-4.4)
>
> Each part MAY have an (optional) `Content-Type` header field, which defaults to `text/plain`.  If the contents of a file are to be sent, the file data SHOULD be labeled with an appropriate media type, if known, or `application/octet-stream`.

While `@` makes a file to get attached in the form as a file upload, the `type` parameter allows you to specify the [`Content-Type`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) of a given part.